# javascript - if and or (||) statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, merge, conditional-statements

```
if (window.location.pathname == "/" || window.location.pathname == "/yyy.asp") {
  runSlideShow();
}
if (
  window.location.pathname == "zzzz.html" ||
  window.location.pathname == "/xxx.html"
) {
  runSlideShow();
}
```

How do I merge the **if** statements so there is only one `{runSlideShow();}` rather than two;

currently I cant seem to have more than two window.location.pathname statements with an || in between.

Comment: What goes wrong when you just combine them into one `if` test? Errors?

Comment: You're not limited in the number of `||`s in one `if` - You can have as many as you like

Comment: tried adding more than 2 || and it fails.. thats why i asked!
thnaks for all the replies, they all look like good solutions.
thanks
Mark

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to both merge your conditions and cut down your code significantly.

```
if (['/', '/yyy.asp', 'zzzz.html', '/xxx.html'].includes(location.pathname))
    runSlideShow();
```

Or alternatively, for the hell of it, shorter still but less readable/scalable:

```
if (/^(?:(\/(yyy\.asp|xxx\.html)?)|zzzz\.html)$/.test(location.pathname))
```

Comment: Welcome. Please accept one of the answers if they solve your problem.

Comment: Careful with the regular expression. When using the bar operator (`|`), things like `^` and `$` are grouped to the left or right. This matches `/blah.xxx.html.json` as a path. Try `/^(?:...)$/` where `...` is the contents you want in the middle.

Comment: The corrected regular expression is [`/^(?:(\/(yyy\.asp|xxx\.html)?)|zzzz\.html)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/zYbiQ9/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (["/", "/yyy.asp", "zzzz.html", "/xxx.html"].includes(window.location.pathname)) { 
  runSlideShow();
}
```

or, full gangsta:

```
["/", "/yyy.asp", "zzzz.html", "/xxx.html"].includes(window.location.pathname) && runSlideShow();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you shouldn't be able to have 4 conditional checks in a single if statement.

```
if (window.location.pathname=="/" || window.location.pathname=="/yyy.asp" || window.location.pathname=="zzzz.html" || window.location.pathname=="/xxx.html") {
  runSlideShow();
}
```

Comment: Sure, but it directly answers their questions without assuming their skill level and potentially confusing them.

Answer (score 0):

You can have different approachto this problem

```
// set array with allowed paths
const pathsForSlideShow = ['/', '/yyyy.asp', 'etc...']; 
// check if path is in array if so run the slidshow
if ( pathForSlideShow.indexOf(window.location.pathname) !== -1 ) runSlideShow();

// or if you don't need to support IE
if ( pathForSlideShow.includes(window.location.pathname) ) runSlideShow();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep your `if` condition as short and sweet as possible. Extract the conditions out to their own functions.

```
if (shouldRunSlideShow()) {
   runSlideShow();
}

function shouldRunSlideShow() {
    return currentPathMatchesAny(["/", "/yyy.asp", "/zzzz.html", "/xxx.html"]);
}

function currentPathMatchesAny(paths) {
    return paths.includes(window.location.pathname);
}
```

Quite verbose code but I think it reads well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
if (["/", "/yyy.asp", "zzzz.html", "/xxx.html"].includes(window.location.pathname)) { 
  runSlideShow();
}
```

Or

```
if (window.location.pathname == "/" || window.location.pathname == "/yyy.asp" || 
window.location.pathname == "zzzz.html" || window.location.pathname == "/xxx.html") 
{
  runSlideShow();
}
```

Comment: @markadlington If you think the answer is useful, please give me a up-vote for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (['/', '/yyy.asp', 'zzzz.html', '/xxx.html'].includes(location.pathname))
runSlideShow();
```

Thanks everybody, i have used this solution.